# capybara is acting weird - "click_link" is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara

Seems all of capybaras methods are magically undefined. I am trying to stub out some tests for TDD and I wrote the following test:

```
  it "sign in and fail" do
    click_link "login"
    fill_in "User Name", :with => "Test"
    fill_in "Password", :with => "test"
    click_button "sign in"
    page.should have_content("User does not exist. Pleae try registering in.")
  end
```

It should freak out on click_link, only because no such link exists, instead it freaks out saying:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `click_link'
```

So I checked my gem file:

```
gem "rspec-rails", :group => [:test, :development]
group :test do
    gem "factory_girl_rails"
    gem "capybara"
    gem "guard-rspec"
    gem 'database_cleaner'
    gem "launchy"
end
```

And then I checked my pec helper, and yes I have:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
```

So what’s with the undefined method error when ever guard runs? It should be telling me "um there’s no link for me to click..." not "I don’t know what click_link" is. It freaks out on visit, click_button, contains and so on.

a far as I know capybara is installed correctly....

Comment: Verify that the spec file is actually requiring the the rspec-helper.  I went through similar once, and it was because the default template for my editor required a different file and it was close enough that I looked past it a couple dozen times while I was tearing my hair out.

Comment: I do indeed have: `require 'spec_helper'` at the top, how ever in the spec_helper I have commented out: `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` because I was getting the error: ` undefined method `use_transactional_fixtures='` @AndyDavis

Comment: Do you have a subject {page} statement?

Comment: And your it {...}  is within a describe/context block?  Just trying to cover the bases.

Comment: I doubt that my other suggestions will be of much use.  Not sure what could be going on.

Comment: I got this error when I forgot to put `it` block. I was putting actual code inside `describe` block.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your env.rb:

```
include Capybara::DSL
```

And then run the test